# About how to understand that multivariate gaussian distribution is an even function

Tags: gaussian, multivariate-statistical-analysis

Multivariate gaussian:

[image]

In slide 5 of [this](https://uvaml1.github.io/2020/slides/2.2_Gaussian.pdf), this gaussian is stated as an even function. I can not see why? I see that power of exponential is something squared like but does exp^something squared mean that the whole function is an even function? I know that function f(x) is even if f(−x)=f(x) but I want to find it directly by looking at it (if possible). What is the point that I should pay attention to get this.

Comment: It's not generally even while it's true that the densities at $x$ and $2\mu-x$ are the same.

Comment: I think they mean even *about the centre point $\mu$*. Note then that if $(x-\mu)$ is reversed in sign, $p$ is unchanged since $(x-\mu)$ features twice and the double negative is positive. Then $p(\mu+a)=p(\mu-a)$ for all $a$; $p$ is *even*, in this sense